# Xamarin ios remote build error (with timeout + error MT0018)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing xamarin on my windows pc. For Xamarin.iOS development i use remote builds with a paired Mac mini (macOS Catalina 10.15.7, xcode 12.4)

On my  windows  PC i use Visual Studio Community 16.9.3

So everything is up to date.

The Problem:
Since I updated the MAC mini to Catalina 10.15.7 and XCode to 12.4, I can no longer build remotely.

However, i can remotly build a minimal-configuration (newly created Xamarin app with just a flyout-menu) .
Local builds on the mac work just fine as well.

Build output:

```
DetectDebugNetworkConfiguration:
2>    DebugIPAddresses: 127.0.0.1
2>_CompileAppManifest:
2>  Directory "bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\MyApp.iOS.app.dSYM" doesn't exist. Skipping.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning : [xma]: A timeout occurred on client build0a77af9cc5a537b61d338ab15a03b52139eb44a0a9dfa40ea90635be0d0a7c5e1524Busra while executing a post for topic xvs/build/compare-items
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning : The operation has timed out.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning :    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__21`2.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 185
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning : [xma]: A timeout occurred on client build0a77af9cc5a537b61d338ab15a03b52139eb44a0a9dfa40ea90635be0d0a7c5e1524Busra while executing a post for topic xvs/build/compare-items
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning : The operation has timed out.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning :    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__21`2.MoveNext() in C:\A\1\230\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 185
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): warning : A timeout occurred on client build0a77af9cc5a537b61d338ab15a03b52139eb44a0a9dfa40ea90635be0d0a7c5e1524Busra while executing a post for topic xvs/build/compare-items
2>  /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch @/Users/buildserver/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/0a77af9cc5a537b61d338ab15a03b52139eb44a0a9dfa40ea90635be0d0a7c5e/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/response-file.rsp --optimize=force-rejected-types-removal --warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView "--gcc_flags=-ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -lc++ -ObjC -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -lz -ObjC -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -lc++ -ObjC -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -ObjC -lc++ -lz -ObjC" 
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(425,3): error MT0018: Unknown command line argument: '/Users/buildserver/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/0a77af9cc5a537b61d338ab15a03b52139eb44a0a9dfa40ea90635be0d0a7c5e/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/MyApp.iOS.exe'
2>          
2>
2>Build FAILED.
```

After long unsuccessful troubleshooting, I even uninstalled + reinstalled VisualStudio and Xcode… without any luck...

i am most grateful for any thoughts and ideas you may have

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version Adaptive problems, I think you should try to upgrade your visual studio for mac version. cleaning the project and clearing the build cache on the Mac. especially '~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs' folder.

and you can check the cache first:

```
 Unknown command line argument: '/Users/buildserver/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/0a77af9cc5a537b61d338ab15a03b52139eb44a0a9dfa40ea90635be0d0a7c5e/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/MyApp.iOS.exe'
```

to check it exists or not.

Comment: Cache is cleard and Visual Studio up to date but the file MyApp.iOS.exe is actually missing.